# Change API display order in Swagger (using Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I am trying to change the displayed method order in `swagger-ui` page using java.

[image]

I need to show first `welcome` later `hello` controller method.

Below is my code.
[image]

Comment: Have you already read https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/732 ?

Answer (score 3):

In the `@ApiOperation` annotation you have an attribute `position` that you can set to change the order. Note that the attribute is deprecated but still works.

Comment: I take a look on your code: a controller should be annotated with `@Api` not `@ApiModel`

Comment: I tried with both annotation also but not working,getting same output .

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/732#issuecomment-100260052) the core developer of spring-fox states the problem very clear:

> Just to be clear, we have an internal model that totally works as
>   expected and functional. The api descriptions and api operations will
>   be sorted as expected from springfox's standpoint. We're only using
>   the swagger models as DTOs to handle the serialization of our internal
>   service models. Once the DTO's are fixed to preserve the ordering this
>   problem will go away.
>
> We can certainly add a note to describe the problem and the cause to
>   the Readme. Other than waiting for swagger core to fix this, there is
>   nothing to do here other than that I'm afraid.

So unless the Open API will fix/ enhance their models it will not work for spring-fox.

Answer (score 0):

**Default -**
{controller-name}-controller
[image: {controller-name}-controller]

**For Custom Name Add -**
@Tag(name="1. YOUR CUSTOM NAME HERE")

on the Controller Class. **Remember, we have used 1 in the name so that it can be on the top.**

Example -

```
@RestController
@Tag(name="1. Project Resource")
public class ProjectResource {...}
```

Add the following to the application.yml file

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    tagsSorter: alpha
```

**Result -**

[image]